# hdf viewer on windows for tables created using pyTables?

Tags: hdf5, pytables

[viTables](http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=10366) only seems to work with python 2.5.  I have downloaded [HDFView](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/index.html), but when I try to open a table I created following [this tutorial](http://www.pytables.org/docs/manual/ch03.html), I get the following error message:

```
Failed to open file C:\tutorial.h5
java.io.IOException: Unsupported fileformat - C:\tutorial.h5
```

Any ideas for getting HDFView to work?
Is there something I need to do when I'm using pyTables from python to make the format more generic?
Any other good HDF viewers?

Btw, I've just discovered PyTables, and I'm really excited about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViTables works for me with python 2.6 on windows. It is supposed also to work with 2.7. 
However the version on the official site did not work for me and crashed. In a [mailinglist posting](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pytables.vitables.user/150) I found the link to the berlios [ftp server](ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/vitables/) where I got a version that works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen ViTables?

http://vitables.berlios.de/